# Formulating an if-else statement with linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How can I formulate the following statement with linear programming?

> If $i \neq j$ then $A[i] \neq A[j]$.

$A$ is a one-dimensional array of size $N$ and $i$ and $j$ are integer indexes of it, both in range $0..N$.

Comment: look at how a Sudoku is typically modeled

Comment: Can you please explain that a little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let binary decision variable $x_{i,k}$ indicate whether $A[i] = k$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_k x_{i,k} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\\
\sum_i x_{i,k} &= 1 &&\text{for all $k$} \tag2\\
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one value to $A[i]$, and
constraint $(2)$ assigns each value exactly once.